# Correct way to close database connection in event of exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, database-connection

Does the following code leave the connection open if there is an exception?

I am using a Microsoft SQL compact edition database.

```
try
{
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);

    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand cmd =
        new SqlCeCommand("SELECT stuff FROM SomeTable", conn))
    {
      // do some stuff
    }

    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
}
```

Surely a  better way would be to declare a connection object before the try, establish a connection inside the try block and close it in a finally block?

```
 SqlCeConnection conn = null;
 try
 {
    conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);

    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand cmd =
        new SqlCeCommand("SELECT stuff FROM SomeTable", conn))
    {
      // do some stuff
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
}
finally
{
    if( conn != null )  conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 31):

The way you are handling `SqlCeCommand` in your code with the help of a `using` block, you could do the same for the `SqlCeConnection`.

```
SqlCeConnection conn;
using (conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   conn.Open();
   using (SqlCeCommand cmd = 
       new SqlCeCommand("SELECT stuff FROM SomeTable", conn))
   {
   // do some stuff
   }
}
```

Note: You can use a `using` block for classes that implement `IDisposable`.

EDIT: This is same as

```
try
{
    conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "...";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I still can't wrap my head around this. From the ref: "If the SqlCeConnection goes out of scope, it is not closed. You must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose."
In your first example you do not "explicitly close the connection".

Comment: When using the `using` statement, it calls `Dispose` method on the object being used, which in turn would call `Close` method, in case of `SqlCeConnection`. Use a tool such as ILSpy to see what code gets executed when `Dispose` is called on `SqlCeConnection`. See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300654%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Use `Using`

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
//put all your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try
catch
finally
```

is the proper way to handle this, because connection should always be closed at the end. but you should check not only that `conn != null`, but also if `conn` state is not `Closed`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `using` around the connection as well as the `SqlCeCommand` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `using` statement, which handles the connection closing without hassles
http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/01/13/773.aspx

Comment: What about other connector like Mysql .net connector and others. @Mamoo

Comment: Any connector, like the Mysql.net provider *should* (and likely does) implement IDisposable on objects like Connection and Command, so "using" can be and should be there as well. Same goes for file access or any time an object crosses into unmanaged code/resources

Answer (score 0):

You Have To Try Following Way.
Because Connection Close In Finally Block

```
try
{
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);

    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand cmd =
        new SqlCeCommand("SELECT stuff FROM SomeTable", conn))
    {
      // do some stuff
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
\\close connection here
}
```