# SqlDataAdapter Close connection method

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have a code like this in my program and I believe  that it's not closing the connection after that the data is getting filled in.

```
public static string ConnectionInfo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;
public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, string table)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionInfo);
        SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn);
        DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
        Adp.Fill(Ds, table);
        return Ds.Tables[table];
    }
```

Is there any problem in this code ?

Comment: Do you actually close the connection somewhere?

Comment: `cnn.Close()` or `using`............?

Comment: refer this link  <a href = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681097/correct-way-to-close-database-connection-in-event-of-exception" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem is that you are not using the `using` statement for the `SqlConnection` and the `DataAdapter`. However, [`DbDataAdapter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) opens and closes the connection implicitely.

```
public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, string table)
{
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionInfo))
    using(SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn))
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        Adp.Fill(tbl);
        return tbl;
    }
}
```

> The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be
>   valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed
>   before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, **then closed**. If
>   the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

Note that

- the `using` statement will close the connection implicitely even on error
- i have used `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` because you're using a single table anyway

**Edit**: i've only just noticed that you are using a parameter for the table-name. You can also use [`DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. That does not change anything.

Comment: I think that the second `using` statement must be included into the first one's brackets.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano: No, the second using is treated as a single statement because of the braces, therefore it is part of the first using(similar to this `if`: `if (true) if (true) {;}`).

Comment: Ah I understood, thanks. I never tried this approach. I always used brackets even for one single line, for better readability. :-)

Comment: @AlbertoSolano: It's a matter of taste, but i prefer this approach since it prevents indentation. Consider that there are even more disposable objects involved like a `SqlCommand`, then you have already three intendations and the relevant code will scroll out of sight. The `SqlConnection` initialization is not interesting. Thats why i always omit the braces.

Answer (score 0):

Add a using statement in order to close the connection reliably.  This ensures that the connection is closed even if an exception occurs. Change your code as follows:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, string table)
    {
        using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionInfo))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn);
            DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
            Adp.Fill(Ds, table);
            return Ds.Tables[table];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Whatever the opening/closing of the connections should be done in try-catch-finally block.

And we should not be using "**using**"
[*using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))]*
block. Because if something goes wrong with the network or any exception cause. Connection is **not closed**. So better to be use try-catch block.

```
    public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, string table)
    {
        DataSet Ds = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionInfo);

        try{
            SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn);
            Adp.Fill(Ds, table);
            return Ds.Tables[table]; 
        }
        catch{
            throw;
        }
        finally{
            cnn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: _"we should not use the using block because if something goes wrong with the network or any exception cause the connection is not closed"_ This is simply wrong, `SqlConnection.Dispose` will call `Close` implicitly, even on error. So actually a simple `using` statement will be translated to your `try/finally`.